# Jackson Polymorphism Deserialize empty JSON object

Tags: json, jackson

I have a Jackson polymorphic question.
I want to deserialize JSON data into polymorphic types. Reading Jackson documentation, I can deserialize JSON data to polymorphic types. However, I have a special case. I have a class structure as follows:

```
class Supreme {
    private String type;
}
class Foo extends Supreme {
   public String label;
}
class Bar extends Supreme {
}
```

Note: Class Bar does not have any other member variable other than the inherited "type" field.

I have transformed that structure to:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use =     JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,property ="type")
@JsonSubTypes({@Type(value = Foo.class, name = "Foo"),@Type(value = Bar.class, name = "Bar") })
class Supreme {
}
class Foo extends Supreme {
    public String label;
}
class Bar extends Supreme {
}

String data=
"[{
   "type": "Foo",
   "label": "abc"
},
{
   "type": "Bar"
}]"
```

If I pass in the above json data like:
`new ObjectMapper().readValue(data, new TypeReference<List<Supreme>>());`

I get something like "Unable to deserialize class Bar out of the END_TOKEN". And I believe that is because the JsonTypeInfo and JsonSubTypes annotations have parsed "type" property and figured out that the 2nd entity in the array should be mapped to Bar class; however it tries to find "something" after the type property in that 2 entity. In other words, Jackson thinks it is an empty JSON object.

*(Note: the above data without the 2nd entry in the array works fine. In other words, we can deserialize to a list containing Foo object since it at least has a property other than "type")*

Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: One comment: you have a typo in `@Type(value = Bar.class, name = "bar")`; I assume it should be "Bar" instead?

Comment: Which Jackson version? Sounds like a bug -- and something like this was fixed during development of Jackson 1.x.

Comment: @StaxMan
That indeed is a typo. Fixed it. But that doesn't change the problem.

Answer (score 1):

By mistake, I was using Jackson 1.5
I bumped to Jackson 1.9 and the exception went away. So there was a bug in Jackson 1.5

Comment: Makes sense -- it sounded familiar. :)